# NSDateFormatterFullStyle without year (NSDateFormatter)

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter

Using the user's currentLocale from the device, I want to have a date format exactly like the one generated for NSDateFormatterFullStyle minus the year:

```
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

> Friday, 21 September (2012)
>
> (2012年)9月21日金曜日

The areas in brackets are what I need removed but get printed.

I've noticed the iPhone app, Living Earth does this and works for all locales, so does the iPhone lock screen. A custom formatter such as, `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM"];` won't change with localisation.

Can anyone shed some light on how to accomplish this? None of the options for date style seem to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18767674/2155985 ?

Answer (score -3):

Date formatter will not change depending on the phone language setting but on the phone locale setting. If you want to change it within your app, you set the date formatter's locale by calling `[dateFromatter setLocale:theLocaleYouWant]`

EDIT
Code for setting the locale

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd MMMM"];

NSLog(@"Current date : %@",[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
// Output vendredi, 21 septembre which is good !
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer how I get the format I need, such as the example I gave above.

Comment: Actually it does... I just tried it and it works ! You get the name of the day localized... Have a look at the code I added. So you had everyting right from the beginning... ;)

Comment: And what about for a US setting, the day should then come at the end. I appreciate your example but I have my doubts that it can be done with custom date format. Parsing the year out also wouldn't work, as this is what gets outputted for Japan: 2012年9月21日金曜日 (Not only is the year now at the start, the kanji for year, 年, gets added)