# NSDateFormatter: Date according to currentLocale, without Year

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

This can't be too difficult..

I want to display a date without the year. For example: "Aug, 2nd" (USA) or "02.08." (GERMANY)
It must work for a bunch of other locales as well.

My only idea so far is to do a normal format with year, and then remove the year-portion from the generated string.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you need to take a look at:

```
+ (NSString *)dateFormatFromTemplate:(NSString *)template options:(NSUInteger)opts locale:(NSLocale *)locale
```

As per the docs:

> Returns a localized date format string representing the given date format components arranged appropriately for the specified locale.
>   Return Value
>   A localized date format string representing the date format components given in template, arranged appropriately for the locale specified by locale.
>
> The returned string may not contain exactly those components given in template, but may—for example—have locale-specific adjustments applied.
>
> Discussion
>
> Different locales have different conventions for the ordering of date components. You use this method to get an appropriate format string for a given set of components for a specified locale (typically you use the current locale—see currentLocale).
>
> The following example shows the difference between the date formats for British and American English:

```
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
NSLocale *gbLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_GB"];

NSString *dateFormat;
// NOTE!!! I removed the 'y' from the example
NSString *dateComponents = @"MMMMd";  //@"yMMMMd";

dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:usLocale];
NSLog(@"Date format for %@: %@",
[usLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[usLocale localeIdentifier]], dateFormat);

dateFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:dateComponents options:0 locale:gbLocale];
NSLog(@"Date format for %@: %@",
[gbLocale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:[gbLocale localeIdentifier]], dateFormat);

// Output:
// Date format for English (United States): MMMM d, y
// Date format for English (United Kingdom): d MMMM y
```

Extra code (add this to the code above):

```
// 
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.locale = gbLocale;
formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat;
NSLog(@"date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]]);
```

See here:
[NSDateFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDateFormatter/dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:)

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly it, except my dateComponents looks like this: @"MMMMd". Thank you.

Comment: Just changed my answer to be complete.

Comment: @scrrr I'm confused. This is the answer I gave you.

Comment: @rmaddy : I wanted to have a date that did not contain the year. Using NSDateFormatter is not the full answer, what I needed was the date-formatString from template.

Comment: @scrrr Which is exactly what I put in my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy oh sorry, I confused your answer. You are right. Upvoting.

Answer (score 20):

The two examples you give are very different from each other. One uses the abbreviated month name while the other uses the 2-digit month number. One uses a day ordinal ("2nd") while the other simply uses the 2-digit day number.

If you can accept using the same general format for all locales then make use of `NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:`.

```
NSString *localFormat = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMM dd" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

The result of this call will give back a format string you can use with `NSDateFormatter setDateFormat:`. The order of the month and day will be appropriate for the locale as well as any additional punctuation that should be added.

But again, this won't solve your exact needs because of the completely different formats you appear to want for each locale.

Comment: I know this is an old question and this solution worked perfectly for me regarding the date. But does anybody know how this is working for times, for example: 16:00 (Germany) and 4:00 pm (USA)?

Comment: @user3191334 Try it and see what happens. If you have a full question, you should post your own question so it gets the attention it deserves.

Answer (score 8):

## Swift 3

```
let template = "EEEEdMMM"
let locale = NSLocale.current // the device current locale

let format = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: template, options: 0, locale: locale)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = format

let now = Date()
let whatYouWant = formatter.string(from: now) // Sunday, Mar 5
```

Play with `template` to match your needs.

[Doc and examples here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to help you determine the template you want.

Comment: What do you mean @JeanNicolas? The `locale` is passed to function `dateFormat(...)` as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers are using an older api released in iOS 4. A newer api that was introduced in iOS 8 is available.

In the apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) for DateFormatter it provides the below sample code for only showing the day and month in a date. You can just pass the `Locale.current` to the DateFormatter if you don't want to specify a specific `locale` (I haven't been able to find out if this is the default implementation so would advise that you always set locale before using `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(_:)` which is suggested in the docs).

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 410220000)

// US English Locale (en_US)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMMd") // set template after setting locale
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // December 31

// British English Locale (en_GB)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMMd") // // set template after setting locale
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // 31 December
```