# Convert a date to English format form Bengali

Tags: ios, nsstring, ios8, nslocalizedstring, nsdatepicker

I have a date picker in my app. The phone is set to Bangladesh local settings. When I select a date from  datepicker is always returns the date in Bengali. It return a date in local format.

Like, it returns **০৬/১১/২০১৪**

but I want it to be **06/11/2014**.

I've tried converting it by date formatter. This is what I tried:

```
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString: self.birthDate.text];

    NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formater setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
    [formater setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[formater stringFromDate:date]);
```

The output is null.

Comment: your dd/MM/yyyy is incorrect...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767330/nsdateformatter-date-according-to-currentlocale-without-year try this

Comment: @AnoopVaidya that's not a very helpful comment, besides, I believe that that's to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrect in your assumption when you say...

> When I select a date from datepicker is always returns the date in Bengali. It return a date in local format.

`UIDatePicker` returns an `NSDate` object. `NSDate` has no formatting at all. It has no language, it is purely a point in time.

When you do this...

```
NSLog(@"%@", someDate);
```

The system will render that point in time into a string and then print it. It is the rendering into a string that contains the format.

I'm guessing what you are doing is this...

1. Get a date from a `UIDatePicker`.
2. Render that date into a `UITextField` in Bengali. (or label, or text view or something)
3. Trying to read the text and store it into a date.
4. Trying to then "convert" the date to an English string.

What you should be doing is just saving the date that comes from the date picker.

Put it into a property or something.

In your above code I think the bit that is failing is actually the first bit...

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString: self.birthDate.text];
```

Because you're not giving it a format it will fail. But this is the wrong way to go about it anyway.

You should have something like this...

```
- (void)datePickerChoseADate
{
    self.date = self.datePicker.date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried but result is same. I saved the picker date in a NSdate instance. But its result is same. Output is: ১৯৭৫-০১-০১ ০৬:১২:১১ +0000

Any guess?