# dateFormatter.dateFromString - Different results on Simulator & Apple TV

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

On Apple TV the result is "date NOT formatted ..."

On Simulator the result is "date formatted ..."

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let lastModifiedDate = "Sun, 01 May 2016 00:46:17 GMT"
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"

        if let lastModifiedDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(lastModifiedDate) {
            resultLabel.text = "date formated \(lastModifiedDate)"
        } else {
            resultLabel.text = "date NOT formated \(lastModifiedDate)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Most likely the locale of your Apple TV is not the same as the one on your Mac (simulator). Depending on the locale, the dateFormatter might not be able to create an NSDate from a string.
You should always use

```
+ (NSString *)dateFormatFromTemplate:(NSString *)template options:(NSUInteger)opts locale:(NSLocale *)locale
```

From the docs:

> Returns a localized date format string representing the given date format components arranged appropriately for the specified locale. Return Value A localized date format string representing the date format components given in template, arranged appropriately for the locale specified by locale.
>   The returned string may not contain exactly those components given in template, but may—for example—have locale-specific adjustments applied.
>   Discussion
>   Different locales have different conventions for the ordering of date components. You use this method to get an appropriate format string for a given set of components for a specified locale (typically you use the current locale—see currentLocale).

**See also:** [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767330/nsdateformatter-date-according-to-currentlocale-without-year/18767674#18767674)

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line. Now it's working.

```
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")
```

Comment: But remember that hardcoding the locale might not be the best experience for your users. The best solution would be to get it working for any locale.